# Trouble trying to set no password for certain cli commands in linux

Tags: linux, command-line, arch-linux, sudo, password

**Computer Environment**

OS: Arch linux - Manjaro

Shell: zsh

**AIM**

I'm trying to enable the following commands **to not require a password input** for my main user account: **ab**

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

**FAILED ATTEMPT**

I've read and have tried to follow some of the online help and got so far as this by using `sudo -i` to create the file `/etc/sudoers.d/ab` with the following code:

```
ab ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
```

**TROUBLESHOOTING ATTEMPTS**

I've tried to make the following edits without success:

- changing `root` to `ALL`
- changing `systemctl` to `/bin/systemctl`
- deleting `sudo`

Each time I make the edit and save, I `cat /etc/sudoers.d/ab` to check that changes were made, and I always open up a new terminal to try out the command, each time trying a combination of the following while still being asked for a password input:

```
sudo systemctl start NetworkManager
sudo /bin/systemctl start NetworkManager
systemctl start NetworkManager
/bin/systemctl start NetworkManager
```

**QUESTIONS**

Is starting a new terminal enough, or do I need to restart my whole system to initiate the changes?

Or maybe I'm forgetting another step?

Comment: I tried using visudo and adding `ab ALL=(ALL:ALL) sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager` but visudo said there were errors on this line.

Comment: I don't think you should include `sudo` as part of the `Cmnd_Spec`

Comment: Thank you, but I tried editing out sudo without success.

Comment: Always use "sudo visudo" to edit.  Try `ab ALL=(ALL) ALL, NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start NetworkManager`

Comment: The command in `sudoers` should use absolute paths, and shouldn't include `sudo` itself (unless you are running `sudo sudo`).

Comment: In the end changing my file in /etc/sudoers.d/ was not having any effect. I went back to using `sudo visudo` and found that no more errors were produced when I used the FULL PATH to the command WITHOUT sudo . Back in the terminal, it worked (didn't require a password) when I used sudo in front of the command. Thanks murum rr0ss0rr and telcom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lines in `/etc/sudoers.d/ab` should probably be like this:

```
ab ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl stop NetworkManager
ab ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/systemctl start NetworkManager
```

With `sudo` and normal, locally stored sudoers.d files (and nothing advanced like sudoers information stored in a LDAP server), any changes to the sudoers files should take effect immediately, with no need to logout/login, start new terminals, or anything like that.

Normally `sudo` will log both successful and failed attempts to use it, so you should look at the appropriate log file (usually either `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`, depending on distribution) for messages from `sudo`. Those messages will include the command the user is attempting to execute through `sudo`, in the exact form you'll need to write it into the sudoers file to allow it.